Rerun if toc, lot, lof or lol changed?
Assume a document has a table of contents, toc.
From my understanding, typically at the beginning of a document,
at the command \tableofcontents,
the file xxx.toc is read to insert the TOC.
After the latex run finished, the TOC may have changed,
so to get the TOC right, the new toc file must be read in
and so latex must be rerun.
Conversely, if the toc file did not change,
at least the TOC is correct and latex need not be rerun,
at least not to get the TOC right.
I think the same applies to the other files mentioned. RIght?

And after the rerun you may need one more rerun, e.g., if the changed ToC also changes the page break.

Right, it’s a repeated process. The more frequently you compile, the less you have to care about this.

BTW: There are tools like latexmk with heuristics to detect the need for more LaTeX runs and try to do as many runs as needed. One part of the heuristic can be a change of the aux file, or changes of toc, lof, lot and several other files, and also rerun messages in the log.

the answer to this question is 'Yes.' but the site doesn't allow answers that short.

@MS-SPO I found out that it is package rerunfilecheck which informs the user, that e.g. toc changed.
I cannot find out how rerunfilecheck can do this: it writes into the log file:
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `manualLMP.toc' has changed. Rerun.
but i can nowhere find an invocation of macro \RerunFileCheck..
It seems to be related with option starttoc.

Sorry, can't follow you: just compile again. That's it usually.
